# How should I use "not A but B" structure in my sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

I want to use the "not A but B" structure to focus attention on a certain perspective.

> I saw the dead bodies of a mother and her son.

This is the statement of fact. I want to use the "not A but B" structure to describe the fact and focus attention on an emotional hook, like the innocence of the child.

Comment: My first observation is that they are not saying the same thing. In the first example it is clear that the son is dead, but the mother could well be living. In the second case it is the other way around.

Comment: The person wants to talk emotionally about that scene! ( both of them are killed) , Some thing like this:"  what I saw wan not a mother next to her dead son,but an innocent baby next to his mom's body", in fact he wants to focus of that child's innocence rather than their being died( for example in a battle )

Comment: The baby isn't innocent, it's guilty; the baby killed the son!!! But seriously though, what exactly are you asking? Your question is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Dear Blubberguy! Sorry for getting confused! I meant that mother and her son were killed for example; by ISIS!! In one sentence the focus is on mother, in the other is on the son!

Comment: Please look at the title of your question -  "not A but B', sentence (singular)  - and then at what you put below that: two sentences, neither of them have the word "not" or "but" in them. As it stands this question is unintelligible. We shouldn't have to look at these comments to work it out.

Comment: Thank you for asking. When a question asks for proofreading or rewriting (“how should I write this?”, “is this correct?”, “which is correct?”), that is out of scope for this site and may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” try asking that question instead. Also check out: “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”.

Comment: @MetaEd, thanks for your explanations.:), As you see, I have already stopped  asking my questions (It’s so stressfull to ask a question here).

Answer (score 4):

You can reword it a few different ways, depending on how formal you want to be. Either of these examples could work for you.

> - I saw not just two dead bodies, but the bodies of an innocent child and his mother.
> - What I saw wasn't two dead bodies: I saw the bodies of an innocent child and his mother.

Of course, you can elaborate however you like.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is what you mean but here is an attempt:

> I saw a dead woman. Not just her but her innocent baby as well.

Comment: You're welcome. If Paul Rowe's answer is correct then please mark it as such so others know that no further answer is needed.